# Delete entire document if array has no element after pull

Tags: mongodb

[Sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6lQ9cuJ0Nvw)

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$pull": {
    "a": {
      x: {
        $lt: ISODate("2022-01-01T00:00:00Z")
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

How do I delete the document if pull results empty array? I don't want to shoot two queries. Thought of using aggregate update using cond. But as per [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), pull is not supported.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do by single query in current mongodb version 5, you have to execute 2 queries.

Comment: @turivishal Glad to hear from you. Thought of the same.